# How to set bootstrap 3 modal width to a grid column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I use bootstrap 3 grid to design a web page with 3 columns.  The grid is defined as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <form action="#">
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        </div>
```

There is a button inside the form.  When that button is clicked, a Bootstrap Modal is shown.

The Modal is defined as follows:

```
<div id="add_element_modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Data Element</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Specify Element Type</h4>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="element_type" id="et_q" value="v1" checked>Option 1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="element_type" id="et_ft" value="v2">Option 2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_add_element">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the Modal is shown, I would like to set its width but failed.  The Modal's width is always the same as the browser width.  I tried to use a row with 3 columns (`col-xs-3`, `col-xs-6`, `col-xs-3`) to confine the modal definition.  Looks that the div `add_element_modal` is not defined properly.  But I could not get it right.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the width of .modal class to use larger modal windows or you can use http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/